# How to fetch hidden span values using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, outerhtml

The page I am trying to test has a span element that is actually functioning as a drop down select menu. The Selenium code for "select" elements does not work and throws the following:

> TC failed with error:
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException:
>   Element should have been "select" but was "span"

Outer HTML:

```
<img id="s_2_1_193_0_icon" class="applet-form-combo" data-allowdblclick="true" src="images/janna/down.gif" alt="Combobox Field" style="display: inline;">
<span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    20 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.
</span>
```

Comment: why tagged with javascript?

Comment: Don't put extra information in comments, edit your question.

Comment: Your code trials please.

Answer (score 0):

Try using attribute `style` while locating web elements that are hidden. Something like below should work:

> driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[style*='hidden']"));

//cross check locator

Talking about JavaScript, you can try below:

> JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver);
>   executor.executeScript(“arguments[0].setAttribute(‘style’,
>   ‘visibility: visible;’);”, element);
>   executor.executeScript(“arguments[0].click();", element);